# KendoUI Angular2 Can I install all the components?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I hope. Kendo Grid, Combobox, treeview ... Kendo all package !

### KendoUI Angular2 Can I install all the components?

```
npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-buttons @progress/kendo-angular-l10n @angular/animations @progress/kendo-angular-grid @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns @progress/kendo-angular-inputs @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs @progress/kendo-data-query @progress/kendo-angular-intl @progress/kendo-drawing @progress/kendo-angular-excel-export
```

I do not want this method.

---

For example, "npm install --save @progress/kendo-ui-angular-allpackage"

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation you have to install kendo plugin using these dependencies

```
npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-buttons @progress/kendo-angular-l10n @angular/animations
```

Reference from here

- http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/

There is no dependency under the package name of

```
npm install --save @progress/kendo-ui-angular-allpackage
```

> According to me Kendo use the pattern of angular like angular did seprate the code in different folders so 
>   when need we need to install using particular package like `@angular/router` etc.